# ¿Cómo usar rutas relativas en python con una ruta base variable?

Tags: python, rutas

Quisiera saber cómo puedo crear una variable con una ruta base, a partir de la cual, con una ruta relativa, se llegue a la ubicación de un archivo.

Por ejemplo, si creo una ruta base:

```
Rutabase = 'C:/Prueba/'
```

y recibo una ruta relativa:

```
Rutarel = 'Carpeta1/Archivo1.txt'
```

El resultado querría que fuera:

```
Rutasol = 'C:/Prueba/Carpeta1/Archivo1.txt'
```

Esto se podría hacer facilmente simplemente sumando a la ruta base la ruta relativa, pero el problema está en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
Rutabase = 'C:/Prueba/Carpeta1/'
Rutarel = '../Archivo_prueba.txt'
Rutasol = 'C:/Prueba/Archivo_prueba.txt'
```

y aquí no me vale la suma.

Según he leído, la solución puede estar relacionada con la variable `os.path`, pero no he encontrado una solución concreta a este problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) para unir las rutas, en el caso de tus dos ejemplos:

```
import os

Rutabase = 'C:/Prueba/'
Rutarel = 'Carpeta1/Archivo1.txt'
Rutasol = os.path.join(Rutabase, Rutarel)
Rutasol = os.path.abspath(Rutasol)
print(Rutasol)

Rutabase = 'C:/Prueba/Carpeta1/'
Rutarel = '../Archivo_prueba.txt'
Rutasol = os.path.join(Rutabase, Rutarel)
Rutasol = os.path.abspath(Rutasol)
print(Rutasol)
```

Obtenemos la salida:

> C:\Prueba\Carpeta1\Archivo1.txt
>   C:\Prueba\Archivo_prueba.txt

Comment: ¡Gracias @FJSevilla! ¡Funcionó a la perfección!

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar un módulo que se llama `Unipath`, que une en un solo paquete funciones relacionadas con las rutas de varios paquetes como `os`, `os.path` y `shutils`.

Mira, primero haciendo una suma normal:

```
In [1]: from unipath import Path

In [2]: rutabase = Path('/home/toledano/share/')

In [3]: rutarel = Path('projects/cmi/LICENCE')

In [4]: rutasol = rutabase + rutarel

In [5]: rutasol
Out[5]: Path('/home/toledano/share/projects/cmi/LICENCE')
```

Y ahora usando rutas relativas:

```
In [1]: from unipath import Path

In [2]: rutabase = Path('/home/toledano/share/')

In [3]: rutarel = Path('../Documents/Projects/v-cmi/README.md')

In [4]: rutasol = rutabase + rutarel

In [5]: rutasol.isabsolute()
Out[5]: True

In [6]: rutasol
Out[6]: Path('/home/toledano/share/../Documents/Projects/v-cmi/README.md')

In [7]: rutasol.resolve()
Out[7]: Path('/home/toledano/Documents/Projects/v-cmi/README.md')
```

Puedes ver la documetación del paquete aquí: https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath

Comment: ¡Gracias Toledano! Me he descargado también Unipath porque me parecieron interesante las posibilidades y de hecho he usado algunas de ellas

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de que la ruta absoluta nunca va llevar la subcadena ../ , simplemente borramos los caracteres problemáticos y ya operamos con os de forma normal:

```
#partiendo de que una ruta base nunca va llevar la subcadena ../
Rutabase = 'C:/Prueba/Carpeta1/'
Rutarel = '../Archivo_prueba.txt'

#simplente eliminamos la posible subcadena ../
aux = Rutarel.replace("../","")
Rutarel = aux

Rutasol = os.path.join(Rutabase, Rutarel)
Rutasol = os.path.abspath(Rutasol)
print(Rutasol)
C:\Prueba\Carpeta1\Archivo_prueba.txt
```